How to define a function using external ! command?
I want to use this command
sed 's/\(^[^#]*\)\(#.*$\)/\2\n\1/;s/ *$//'

in a Vim function.
In my .vimrc I've tried this:
function! myfunc1() range
  execute a:firstline . ',' a:lastline . '!sed s/\(^[^#]*\)\(#.*$\)/\2\n\1/;s/ *$//'
endfunction

When I run it in "Visual mode linewise" with Shift+V, it gives me the error:
E194: No alternate file name to substitute for '#': 85811, 85817!sed s/\(^[^#]*\)\(#.*$\)/\2\n\1/;s/ *$//

If I remove "sed" and use Vim commands, it gives me this error:
E488: Trailing characters: ;s/ *$//

The sed command standalone works fine.
Why it this?


The sed command standalone works fine

Well no, and that is your first problem.
In Vim, you would use your sed command like so:
:'<,'>!sed s/\(^[^#]*\)\(#.*$\)/\2\n\1/;s/ *$//

but it throws an error as-is so turning it into a function would be useless at that point. It should be fixed first, and iterating is a lot easier in the command-line.
So the error is caused by your two #s: when there is a # in an external command, Vim tries to expand it into the filename of the "alternate file". This is generally useful but in this case it is a problem for two reasons:

Because it can fail if there is no alternate file, as is the case here.
Because you actually don't want your # to be expanded to begin with.

You can prevent expansion by escaping # with a backslash:
:'<,'>!sed s/\(^[^\#]*\)\(\#.*$\)/\2\n\1/;s/ *$//

But you are not done yet, as the shell doesn't like what you are trying to do, because it is incorrect:
/bin/bash: line 1: s/: No such file or directory

Not only the ; is interpreted by your shell as a command separator, but it will also misinterpret s/ *$// as a command and its argument because of the space between s/ and *$//.
It turns out that, contrary to your core assumption, your sed command is actually broken to begin with, which you should have seen if you had tested the command in your shell first.
You must surround the sed command with double quotes in order for it to be treated as a single argument:
:'<,'>!sed "s/\(^[^\#]*\)\(\#.*$\)/\2\n\1/;s/ *$//"

There, no errors.
Note that you didn't provide any sample text so I can't test it further. Assuming the provided sed command actually does what you want, your function should now look like this:
function! myfunc1() range
  execute a:firstline . ',' a:lastline . '!sed "s/\(^[^\#]*\)\(\#.*$\)/\2\n\1/;s/\ *$//"'
endfunction

Which is still not good because custom functions must start with an uppercase letter:
E128: Function name must start with a capital or "s:": myfunc1() range
line    2:
E121: Undefined variable: a:firstline
line    3:
E193: :endfunction not inside a function

That is easy to fix:
function! Myfunc1() range
  execute a:firstline . ',' a:lastline . '!sed "s/\(^[^\#]*\)\(\#.*$\)/\2\n\1/;s/\ *$//"'
endfunction

Now let's make the concatenation explicit since we are at it:
function! Myfunc1() range
  execute a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . '!sed "s/\(^[^\#]*\)\(\#.*$\)/\2\n\1/;s/\ *$//"'
endfunction

And use the recommended .. instead of .:
function! Myfunc1() range
  execute a:firstline .. ',' .. a:lastline .. '!sed "s/\(^[^\#]*\)\(\#.*$\)/\2\n\1/;s/\ *$//"'
endfunction

Nice, but… why all that indirection when you can do the same thing right within Vim itself with :help :s?
See :help cmdline-special, :help alternate-file, :help define-function, :help expr-...

Upvoted for pointing out that plain :s gets the job done and OP really does not need to use an external command at all.

@Friedrich there is an additional ..

If you're curious how this could be done in vim9script:
vim9script

def SplitComments(line1: number, line2: number)
    silent exe $':{line1},{line2}s/\(^[^#]*\)\(#.*$\)/\2\r\1/'
    silent :'[,']s/ *$//
enddef

command! -range SplitCom SplitComments(<line1>, <line2>)


this is "legacy" vimscript
func! SplitComments() range
    silent exe $':{a:firstline},{a:lastline}s/\(^[^#]*\)\(#.*$\)/\2\r\1/'
    silent :'[,']s/ *$//
endfunction

command! -range SplitCom call SplitComments()

As for your original question why your command doesn't work:
:h :! states that "Also, all |cmdline-special| characters in {cmd} are    replaced by Vim before passing them to shell." where # is replaced with alternate file name. Same happens to any filter command  :h :range!.
What you can do here is to use shellescape() function:
...
        The {special} argument adds additional escaping of keywords
        used in Vim commands. When it is not omitted and a non-zero
        number or a non-empty String (|non-zero-arg|), then special
        items such as "!", "%", "#" and "<cword>" (as listed in
        |expand()|) will be preceded by a backslash.
        This backslash will be removed again by the |:!| command.
...

Which could be used as:
func! SplitComments() range
    exe $':{a:firstline},{a:lastline}!sed {shellescape('s/\(^[^#]*\)\(#.*$\)/\2\n\1/;s/ *$//', 1)}'
endfunction

command! -range SplitCom <line1>,<line2>call SplitComments()


